# DOM elements memory allocation management on Xerces-C

Tags: c++, xml, dom, xml-parsing, xerces-c

It has been two days for me to struggle on xml parsing problems and it still hasn't finished yet :)

Well, After many trils I finally decided to use Xerces-C to parse xml in my c++ application.

Well... I tried TinyXml, RapidXml and others.... Xerces too behave in the same way when managing nodes on the point of view of memory allocation.

Well, DOMElement, DOMDocument, DOMNode tey all are private construct classes... I know it is for ensuring best performance when parsing but it gets really a bad thing when trying to manage nodes between classes.

I have this problem.
I would like to create a class that stores an xml document (a DOM object that has all nodes I want and that I can navigate freely, so it is not a string var, but a DOM obj, I suppose a DOMElement/DOMDocument is good). Well, this object is a member of my class. Using functions in my class I want to let this DOM Tree grow in time... Internally I keep the tree and when I want i print it to a file.
This is what I want to do. I know that it seems weird but this is my requirement. I must do so, every other solution is not to be considered... sorry. (I should tell you the reason why this is the implementation, but it would take much time).

Expressing this in code, the following lines are the representation of what I would like to achieve:

```
class MyTree {
public:
    MyTree();
    ^MyTree(); // It is a tilde :)
    // Methods
    void AddToTree(std::string el); // Adds a new node somewhere in the DOM
    std::string GetTree(); // Inserts the tree in a string
private:
    DOMDocument _xmldoc;
};
```

Considering all restrictions caused by private constructors, and that I can get a DOMDocument only from a XercesDOMParser, and I get the pointer, how can I achieve this...
If in the constructor I do so:

```
MyTree::MyTree() {
    XercesDOMParser parser;
    parser.parse(XMLString::transcode("<...>...</...>"));
    this->_xmldoc = parser.getDocument();
}
```

After assigning to _xmldoc the document, the constructor function goes out of scope and parser is deleted, and so every component owned by it, so my _xmldoc will point to nothing...

How can I solve this problem???

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the parser around. Either pass it as an argument (by reference), make it a member of `MyTree` (again, as a reference), or put it in a singleton class.

(`_xmldoc` should be a pointer, btw.)

Comment: Yes, I opted to keep the parser and I was not sure for this to be a correct way to proceed... but if you say so... well thankyou.

Comment: It's the only way, unfortunately. I've been amazed at the design of this library before.